# Autonomylab create_autonomy launch error

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm following [instructions to create_autonomy](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy), but I keep getting the following error:

> [create_2.launch] is neither a launch file in package [ca_driver] nor is [ca_driver] a launch file name. The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?